# "Bada" - what's going on with this javascript snippet

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop and create several calendars on a page.

I'm failing.

My loop is returning "bada" - what's that?

```
for (i=1; i<3; i++) {
$("#jqxCalendar" + i).jqxCalendar({
width: '200px',
height: '200px',
enableTooltips: true
});
alert (i);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8oorztjt/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your loop, you forgot to put the `var` keyword before the `i`. As such, it appears you aren't referring to the `i` index it would appear you are. I don't know what the `i` variable is being used for elsewhere that it's containing the string "bada", but changing your first line to `for (var i=1; i<3; i++) {` will create a new variable `i` and cause your loop to behave as you are expecting.

Comment: even if the calendar change the value of **i** when looping ?

Comment: Why would the calendar change the value of an external variable that isn't used by it? Try the code, it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you. So where the word **bada** comes from? and how the code works when I change the name of **i** to another name?

Answer (score 1):

change **i** to other parameter like **ii** .it seems **i** is in use with that calendar.